# Kronecker's 1870 paper on finite Abelian Groups??

Tags: math-history

Could anyone please provide me with the exact bibliographic reference for Kronecker's 1870 work on finite Abelian groups? If you could provide me with his exact formulation (or even with a acanned copy of it from the book) it would be great.

Thnak in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L. Kronecker, *Auseinandersetzung einiger Eigenschaften der Klassenzahl idealer complexer Zahlen*, Monatsbericht der Königlich-Preussischen Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin, 1870, pp. 881-889. The entire volume is freely available at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/monatsberichtede1870unse) in a variety of formats. You can read it online or download PDFs of individual pages at the [Biodiversity Heritage Library](http://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/133986#page/5/mode/1up) or at the [Berlin-Brandenburgische Akademie der Wissenschaften Akademiebibliothek](http://bibliothek.bbaw.de/bibliothek-digital/digitalequellen/schriften/anzeige/index_html?band=09-mon/1870&seite:int=891).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Javier: You’re very welcome.

Comment: Here it is, in case someone other than me wants to have a look at it: http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/5761094